# Oracle UNION not working

Tags: database, oracle, stored-procedures

I have an Oracle Stored Proc - called from Java 1.6 code. There's a message that is sent out to a number and the number can reply on it. My problem is that the UNION part is not working.
I want one row returned with the message and reply on one row. What happens at the moment is the stored proc returns 2 rows. The 1st row has only the message. The 2nd row has them combined. I want only the 2nd row.

Here is my stored proc:

```
  create or replace
  FUNCTION "LIST_ALL_MSGS_SERVICE" (
gvi_service_code_in     in varchar2,
start_date_in           in varchar2,
end_date_in         in varchar2
)
  return types.cursorType
  is
     msg_cursor types.cursorType;
     l_msg_code message.gvi_message_code%type;
     l_start_date   date;
     l_end_date date;

  BEGIN
     IF start_date_in IS NULL THEN
        raise_application_error(-20054, 'start_date missing');
    END IF;
    IF end_date_in IS NULL THEN
        raise_application_error(-20054, 'end_date missing');
    END IF;

 /*  Set end date */

    l_end_date := to_date(end_date_in, 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss');

/*  Set start date  */
    l_start_date := to_date(start_date_in, 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss');


/*  Use cursor to select messages  */
BEGIN
   OPEN msg_cursor FOR
      SELECT
        m.message_id,
          m.gvi_message_code  sort_gvi_message_code,
              m.recipient,
              m.originator,
              m.content,
              mct.message_channel_type,
              to_char(m.message_date, 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'),
              mst.description,
              null,
              null,
        m.gvi_datafeed_name
         FROM message m,
            message_channel_type mct,
              message_status_type mst,
        message_status ms
    WHERE TRIM(UPPER(m.gvi_service_code)) = gvi_service_code_in
    AND m.gvi_message_code = ms.gvi_message_code
    AND m.message_date >= l_start_date
          AND m.message_date <= l_end_date
    AND m.message_channel_type_id = mct.message_channel_type_id
          AND ms.message_status_type_id = mst.message_status_type_id
    AND ms.message_status_type_id =
    (SELECT MAX(ms2.message_status_type_id)
    FROM message_status ms2
      WHERE ms2.gvi_message_code = m.gvi_message_code)

UNION
SELECT
        m.message_id,
              m.gvi_message_code  sort_gvi_message_code,
              m.recipient,
              m.originator,
              m.content,
              mct.message_channel_type,
              to_char(m.message_date, 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'),
              mst.description,
              em.gvi_external_message_code,
              em.content,
        m.gvi_datafeed_name
         FROM message m,
          external_message em,
          ext_msg_status_type emst,
              message_channel_type mct,
              message_status_type mst,
        message_status ms
    WHERE TRIM(UPPER(m.gvi_service_code)) = gvi_service_code_in
    AND m.gvi_message_code = ms.gvi_message_code
    AND m.gvi_message_code = em.gvi_message_code
    AND TRIM(UPPER(emst.ext_msg_status_type)) = 'REPLY'
    AND em.ext_msg_status_type_id = emst.ext_msg_status_type_id
    AND m.message_date >= l_start_date
          AND m.message_date <= l_end_date
    AND m.message_channel_type_id = mct.message_channel_type_id
          AND ms.message_status_type_id = mst.message_status_type_id
      AND ms.message_status_type_id =
    (SELECT MAX(ms2.message_status_type_id)
    FROM message_status ms2
      WHERE ms2.gvi_message_code = m.gvi_message_code)
  ORDER BY sort_gvi_message_code;

END;

RETURN msg_cursor;
  commit;
  END list_all_msgs_service;
```

Comment: Why are you unioning; are you trying to show the initial message on its own if there was no reply, and the message and its reply together if there was?

Comment: That is correct. If there is a message with no reply - only the message must be shown. If there is a message with replies - the message and the replies must show

Comment: fixed tags, this has nothing to do with Java

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The union is working, it finds different values in the `selects` if there is a reply. It just isn't doing what you want. You could add a `and not exists ()` clause to the first part of the union so it doesn't return anything if the second half will, but it would be easier and have a lot less repetition to use an outer join for this - so you only have a single `select` and no `union`:

```
   SELECT m.message_id,
          m.gvi_message_code  sort_gvi_message_code,
          m.recipient,
          m.originator,
          m.content,
          mct.message_channel_type,
          to_char(m.message_date, 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'),
          mst.description,
          em.gvi_external_message_code,
          em.content,
          m.gvi_datafeed_name
     FROM message m
     JOIN message_status ms
       ON m.gvi_message_code = ms.gvi_message_code
     JOIN message_status_type mst
       ON ms.message_status_type_id = mst.message_status_type_id
     JOIN message_channel_type mct
       ON m.message_channel_type_id = mct.message_channel_type_id
LEFT JOIN external_message em
       ON m.gvi_message_code = em.gvi_message_code
LEFT JOIN ext_msg_status_type emst
       ON em.ext_msg_status_type_id = emst.ext_msg_status_type_id
      AND TRIM(UPPER(emst.ext_msg_status_type)) = 'REPLY'
    WHERE TRIM(UPPER(m.gvi_service_code)) = gvi_service_code_in
      AND m.message_date >= l_start_date
      AND m.message_date <= l_end_date
      AND ms.message_status_type_id =
          (SELECT MAX(ms2.message_status_type_id)
             FROM message_status ms2
            WHERE ms2.gvi_message_code = m.gvi_message_code)
 ORDER BY sort_gvi_message_code;
```

Untested, obviously. The left outer joins mean that if there is no reply, the `em.gvi_external_message_code` and `em.content` values will be `null`, which is what you want from the first part of your existing union. I think.

Comment: Just tested this and it works - you are a damn genius! ha :) thank you so much!